# "this is undefined" in static function

Tags: typescript, undefined, this

```ts
class Example{
    static foo():string{
        return this.bar();
    }

    static bar():string{
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Broken{
    static breaksThis(callback: () => string):string{
        return callback();
    }
}

console.log(Example.foo()); // works
console.log(Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo)); // Error at line 3: "this is undefined"
```

An interactive Example can be found [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTA3gKGn6EALmIQJbDQBmA9tQBQCUAXEQE6kB2A5jvn9K3SEArqw7RCAC1IQAdACMwrRgG5c+AL7Z1eIiXLRFy5m048d-QSLHQAREdtq+WrdlCQYAIVbUA1ug5efD0yCnlBMF8IABVpCDpgMBAQRWBfJmhGaABeAD4CQnZuE0KzIP4BIVFxROTU31ULF21gag4IagxZEGouOgRkNHRZGnoGBhVoAHop6AB3alYotzaOrp6+7z8AhQio2Jl+xFQu0fHJmbhWH1ZoEmgQTnRoAGYM2ykZaC-hDgATdCUJ5-WzYIA).

I would like to understand why the first log works as intended but the second fails. And how could I fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Also relevant: [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429)

Comment: in the foo function have ```return Example.bar();``` instead of ```this```

Answer (score 3):

You are abusing `this` in a static method of a class.
Try this in order to fix:

```js
class Example {
    static foo(): string {
        return Example.bar(); /* Here is the fix */
    }

    static bar(): string {
        return "bar";
    }
}

class Broken {
    static breaksThis(callback: () => string): string {
        return callback();
    }
}

console.log(Example.foo()); // works
console.log(Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo));
```

Comment: I like your workaround but its not correct. In TypeScript the `this` in a static function refers to the **current** class (inheritance respecting)

Comment: @Verim "*TypeScript the this in a static function refers to the current class (inheritance respecting)*" incorrect.

Comment: @VLAZ do you have a source? All IDE and compiler are working like I descripe

Comment: @Verim is your very example not enough to prove the opposite? [Here is another example](https://tsplay.dev/Nal06w) that shows `this` is still resolved at call time. Moreover, you can just look at the generated JS code. At no point is `this` being bound. [See also](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript)

Comment: @VLAZ, so is it a mistake by TypeScript to allow us to use the `this` keyword inside static methods then?

Comment: No, it's not. It's a tradeoff - you really shouldn't be mishandling `this` and if you don't, then everything works. Disallowing the usage of `this` just because the programmer might mishandle it is a bit like throwing away all the knives in the kitchen because you might grab one by the blade.

Answer (score -1):

[Working Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTA3gWAFDQOggBcxiBLYaAMwHtaAKASgC4SAncgOwHMd9Cg9umIBXdlziJUGAHQAjMO2YBuPIIC+edYRJlK0RctYdufHYILCxE6ACIjdtQIJbcbvKEgwAQu1oA1uhc-IJ6FFTywmABEAAqABbkEAzAwGAgIIrAASzQzNAAvAB8RMScvCblZqGW0NbikmkZWWA5qhbQbh64wLRcELRyILQ8DAjIaOiydIxMTCrQAPRL0ADutOyxnv2Dw6MMfoHBCtGxicnj0lMz9POLK3Ds-uzQZNAg3OjQAMx5dsQkjBktBRFwACboahfcF2IA)

```js
    class Example{
        static foo():string{
            return Example.bar();
        }

        static bar():string{
            return "bar";
        }
    }

    class Broken{
        static breaksThis(ccallback: () => string):string{
           return ccallback();
        }
    }

    console.log(Example.foo()); // works
    console.log(Broken.breaksThis(Example.foo));
```